# Unable to set up default credentials for official Mongo docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am using `docker-compose` to launch an official `mongodb` database container.

Reading the scripts and some StackOverflow questions looks like MONGO_INITDB_ environment variables can be used to set default credentials.

After running the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.6
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=collection
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

And trying to connect with `mongo` cli or `mongoose` Node.js ODM I get authentication error:

```
➔ mongo -u user -p password --verbose localhost:27017/collection
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: localhost:27017/collection
2018-04-10T12:29:46.386+0200 creating new connection to:localhost:27017
2018-04-10T12:29:46.386+0200 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2018-04-10T12:29:46.387+0200 connected to server localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1)
2018-04-10T12:29:46.387+0200 connected connection!
2018-04-10T12:29:46.391+0200 User Assertion: 18:{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18, codeName: "AuthenticationFailed" }
2018-04-10T12:29:46.392+0200 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18, codeName: "AuthenticationFailed" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1287
2018-04-10T12:29:46.392+0200 User Assertion: 12514:login failed
2018-04-10T12:29:46.393+0200 freeing 1 uncollected N5mongo12DBClientBaseE objects
exception: login failed
```

Connecting to `/admin` collection as defined in the entrypoint script [1] gave the same result. I am unable to see what am I doing wrong.

EDIT: Derick, from `irc.freenode.org` `#mongodb` channel, suggested that it may be not picking the `--auth` flag. I tried to log in without credentials (`mongo --verbose localhost:27017/admin`) and it worked. I am still having the issue of establishing defaults credentials, so issue is not yet solved.

[1] https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/b96fddd1e1a100c01f0ea6d28e1c7ccc750fd5c0/3.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L292